# no loading div on click if login fields are empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC 4.0

I am creating a login page , I have used a Loading GIF to display after clicking of login button and before loading of actual page.

My problem is even the login fields are empty and I click Login button, the animation starts showing.

Loading animation should only be seen on successful login.

Button:

```
<input type="submit" name="mySubmit" value="Login" class="btn" onclick="load()"/>
```

Javascript=

```
<script type= "text/javascript">function load(){$('#loading').show();}</script>
```

Please Help !!

Comment: have you tried anything so far, if yes please share

Comment: what is there in `load()` function, please share it in your post (use edit link to edit your post)

Comment: Post your HTML and any relevant info as guessing makes one frustrated!

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar - I have edited and mentioned the load function, now please suggest ?

Comment: are you having any form in your html code that you are submitting on click of button? How are you submitting your login request to navigate to another page, are there any validation before submitting?

Comment: I am using mvc, on button click HttpPost action result is called and after validating I am redirected to different view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do following changes in your code to resolve loading image issue -

first change input type value from `submit` to `button` -

```
<input type="button" name="mySubmit" value="Login" class="btn" onclick="load()"/>
```

And then put empty fields validation check in `load()` function and submit form only if both the fields are filled -

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
  function load(){
    //check if both login fields are empty
    var loginUser = $('#yourLoginUserId').val().trim();
    var loginPassword = $('#yourLoginPasswordId').val().trim();

    if(loginPassword!='' && loginUser!='')
    {
      $('#loading').show();
      $('#yourFormId').submit();
    }
    else
    {
      alert('Please enter Login details');
    }
  }
</script>
```

**NOTE** - please replace fields and form id with actual ids in your code.

Comment: you need to land on same page if credential is wrong but you can show loading because ultimately you are going to backend system for validating credentials.

Comment: thanx ...!! I used ur code with little changes.... I left the else part blank because m also using jquery.validate.min.js for validations.... So I am now only checking whether fields are empty or not... !!